# Bluestacks Home Screen

Tags: bluestacks

I had installed BlueStacks and the home screen was like an Android tablet in landscape mode. Due to some problem COC game was not working, I uninstalled and reinstalled BlueStacks. Now the home screen is showing app categories and apps to download. How can I get back to the previous homescreen which was like a tablet?
Installing lauchers turns the screen in to portrait mode.
pls help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking actually. Do you want to set up BlueStack as tablet, or phone on landscape mode? I never install BlueStack, so I'm not sure either, but check the installation step carefully. Also, if by "app categories and apps to download" means Play Store, then you can just tap back. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Install [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) from Play Store. After you install Apex launcher open it and set it as the default laucher by pressing Home button and selecting Use default option. Some games require your device to be played in portrait mode and it will switch back to landscape once you exit the game, so I guess you Bluestacks is corrupted. So if using the default setting of Apex din't switch to the landscape mode try the following.

If it still is in Portrait mode then, select the "Tablet UI mode" under

```
Apex Settings > Home Screen Settings > Tablet UI mode
```

This way your homescreen will be displayed in landscape mode overtaking the default portrait mode. Even if the above settings don't work for you I recommend you to completely uninstall the Bluestacks which means you need to remove the data of you Bluestacks app when prompted while uninstalling the Bluestacks Player. This would redownload the app data while installing the Bluestacks again and you would have a fresh installation of Bluestack working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Install *Nova Launcher* from the *Play Store* and then in settings of the nova app you can change the orientation.

However to uninstall a launcher go to the settings of bluestacks (somewhere at the statusbar) and uninstall the custom launcher.